# Scraping large number of similar webpages - can I wrap read_html() in an apply() function in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rvest

I am scraping a website that features a large number of dropdown items on the page that changes the values in the table I am scraping. The URLs are dictated by the dropdown values, and I was able to create a vector of all of the URLs I want to scrape. This vector is in the following form:

```
vectorsURL = c("http:www.mywebsite.com/page1/stats.html",
               "http:www.mywebsite.com/page2/stats.html", 
               "http:www.mywebsite.com/page3/stats.html", 
               "http:www.mywebsite.com/page4/stats.html", 
               "http:www.mywebsite.com/page5/stats.html", 
               "http:www.mywebsite.com/page6/stats.html")
```

The full vector is rather long, 25,000 URLs. My current approach for scraping all of these pages is the following, featuring a bit of piping which I'm trying to get in the habit of doing:

```
all_data = c()
for(i in 1:length(vectorsURL)) {
    my_URL = vectorsURL[i]
    scraped_page = my_URL %>%
                     read_html() %>% 
                     html_nodes('table') %>%
                     extract(3) %>%
                     html_table() %>%
                     as.data.frame()

    all_data = rbind(all_data, scraped_page)
}
```

At roughly 2 seconds per page, for 25000 pages this will take upwards of 13-14 hours. I was wondering if this could be done quicker using apply functions. I tried using lapply in the following manner (I tested this on a subset of only 50 URLs) with the following code:

```
b = lapply(temp, FUN = function(x) x %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('table') %>% extract(3) %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame())
```

However this approach took ~100 seconds, which is as long as it would take in the for loop. Any thoughts on speeding this up would be greatly appreciated, even if it involves further parallelization in R in order to read more pages in a shorter amount of time. Thanks!

Comment: `purrr::map_df` may save you a bit of code, though I'm not sure it will change the time significantly. Profile your code, and I suspect the bottleneck is your internet connection. Also, is it really necessary to scrape 25k links? I can't think any site would love that traffic, so if it's legally scrapable in the first place, there may be more efficient sources (e.g. an API or bulk data).

Comment: great point. i don't see on the website if it mentions whether scraping is allowed or not. but I may reach out to the guy that made the site.

Comment: There are a few ways to speed it up but be careful you don't hit the same server too many times because it will look like a ddos. One option is wrap all in `parallel::mclapply` the other is to use `curl` and call `multi_run` on 100 urls at a time.